# How do I make a method like int.getRed() in java?

Tags: java, methods

I am making an imaginary number graphing calculator with java (using a+bi={a,b}) and want to make new functions for + - * / and ^ operators, since they don't work on double[] variables. I know how to make normal methods, like File(), but I am having trouble doing things like int.getRed(). Here's my code for the addition method

```
private static double[] CPlusC(double[] a, double[] b) {
    double aN = a[1] + b[1];
    double bN = a[2] + b[2];
    double[] ansN = {aN,bN};
    return ansN;
}
```

I have the addition parts correct, I just can't find anything to make the function more "realistic", as in `double[].CPlusC(double[])`
Could someone please help me out? Once I figure this one out, I should know how to do the others.
Thank you so much!

Comment: What do you mean by "realistic"? It looks like you want to write something like an extension method like in Kotlin or C# which would allow you to extend existing types by giving them additional methods. Java unfortunately doesn't support extension methods, so you're stuck with using `double[] result = MyUtilClass.CPlusC(firstArray, secondArray)`.

Comment: You can't call methods on Java primitives. Also, Java doesn't have operator overloading.

Comment: You might consider creating a class (`Complex` might be a good name).  The class could then contain the methods to do the basic operations plus anything else that could be deemed appropriate for complex values.

Comment: What has `getRed` got to do with complex numbers? Do you mean `getReal`?

Comment: I am relating getRed() to the format of method that I wanted. Now I have a much better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you can't create extension methods like you would do in [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html) or [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

But you shouldn't use `double[]` to handle complex numbers in the first place. A better approach would be to create your own `Complex` class that contains all necessary methods you need for calculation.

Your class could look like this:

```
public class Complex {
    private final double re;
    private final double im;

    public Complex(double re, double im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }

    // getters and other methods

    public Complex add(Complex other) {
        double addedRe = re + other.re;
        double addedIm = im + other.im;
        return new Complex(addedRe, addedIm);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s %si", re, im < 0 ? "-" : "+", Math.abs(im));
    }
}
```

Then you can do your calculations like:

```
Complex c1 = new Complex(0, 1);
Complex c2 = new Complex(2.5, 1.3);
Complex c3 = c1.add(c2);
System.out.println(c3) // 2.5 + 2.3i
```

Comment: To keep the signs consistently spaced (and correct) I would do `return String.format("%s %s %si", re, im < 0 ? "-" : "+", Math.abs(im))`

Comment: @WJS thanks, I've used your suggestion. The problem is that you need to handle the correct sign yourself for displaying the complex number. This solution should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will do as much as I can with this.